# How to expose gRPC in Istio

Tags: grpc, istio

Anyone know if it is possible to use gRPC with Istio-ingress or other ways?

Yes/no, anything is welcome - thanks in advance.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grpc-service
spec:
  # type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: grpc
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    name: grpc
    # protocol: HTTP2
    targetPort: 3000

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grpc-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "istio"
    # ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /ghw/.*
        backend:
          serviceName: grpc-service
          servicePort: 3000
```

Go code:

```
const (
    address     = "localhost/ghw/:3000"
)
```

Comment: Is `HTTP2` mandatory for your case?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I would like to have a mobile client app to use gRPC? Using Unary RPC would work, but I am new to gRPC and using  Server streaming RPC looks like a big win for a messages feature. Do you know if gRPC can work with Istio? Thanks

Comment: I do not have an example right now, but there should not be any problems with it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50171896/how-to-expose-grpc-in-istio#) and the issue discussed [here](https://github.com/istio/issues/issues/87) with similar configuration of yours drove me -no matter the issue is still open, there are some solutions by the users among the posts.

Comment: And my `HTTP2` thing was alongside with the issue [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/pull/146). There seems older Http1.1 solutions than 2.